# How to fix empty query string from url

Tags: express, vue.js

I am building an app with vue js, express and mongoDB. I want to use url queries to search through collection. but i cant get the query from url

When i get to this url ../races?title=Stadions the client will call the service to get the route. i think this is where the query string gets lost. let me show you.

this is the code from client side:

```
async getRaces () {
      const response = await RacesService.getRaces()
      this.races = response.data.races
    },
```

The RaceService gets called

Then in RaceService this happens:

```
getRaces () {
    return Api().get('races/')
  },
```

That calls the route in the routes file:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    ...
})
```

When doing req.query its empty. And i think its because of the way i call the route because if I do this in RacesService it works correctly:

```
getRaces () {
    return Api().get('races/?title=Stadions')
  },
```

Can someone help me how to fix this?

Comment: What to you want to fix? No params in url means no req.query, that's normal, isnt it?

Comment: Oh yes i wasnt clear enough. I meant to say when i go to that url with the query strings. /routes?title=Stadions

Comment: req.query in express contain an object reflecting the url after the ? sign. What is your problem? Consider rewrite your question more clearly and with entire but small code containing your problem.

Comment: Also, Consider add console.log to see if you really go to the route you think you go.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/). If yes, then you can pass along your query parameters, which are found in `this.$route.query`. That property is an object, so you will probably need a library such as [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) to stringify the query.

Example code:

```
async getRaces () {
  const response = await RacesService.getRaces(this.$route.query)
  this.races = response.data.races
}

//...
import queryString from 'query-string'

getRaces (query) {
  return Api().get('races/?' + queryString.stringify(query))
},
```